# Can't get IMEI as device owner on Android 10

Tags: android

For a special kiosk setup I need the IMEI of the device. Since Android 10 it is not possible for regular apps to access device identifiers like the IMEI. However the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getImei(int)) suggests:

> This API requires one of the following:
>
> - If the caller is the device or profile owner, the caller holds the Manifest.permission#READ_PHONE_STATE permission.
> - ...

I've set the app as device owner with the following command:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.xxxx.xxxx/.AdminReceiver
```

My manifest contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

The IMEI is accessed with the following lines of code:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

try
{
    return telephonyManager.getImei();
}
catch (SecurityException e)
{
    return null;
}
```

I'm still getting SecurityExceptions (with message: `The user does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that `READ_PHONE_STATE` is a [`dangerous` permission that needs to be requested at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting). Beyond that, you might consider logging the exception and examining its message for more details.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on Android 10. My app is set as device owner thanks to ADB and have the good permission requested at runtime as you wrote @CommonsWare. I checked in Settings app. But I still have the same SecurityException. Is this solution definetly blocked since July 2020 as mentionned vmayorow in the below answer ? If you have an idea to have the IMEI, please give a help. Thanks

Comment: @odgatelmand: The documentation has not changed, so my assumption is that the recipe that dan used should work. However, I have not personally attempted to access the IMEI this way -- my answer was based on dan's work based on my original comment.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I just tryed on other devices with Android 10 and it seems that on some build of Android 10, IMEI is not returned as mentionned below by @vmayorow

Comment: As the device owner app you can grant the dangerous permission programatically: [setPermissionGrantState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setPermissionGrantState). Also I agree some devices still do not provide the imei even if you have done everything correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`READ_PHONE_STATE` is a `dangerous` permission. For Android 6.0+, you need to [request it at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) in addition to having it the manifest. Alternatively — particularly for a one-off app installation — you could go into the system Settings app and manually grant the permission.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Android 10 restricts IMEI access to system apps only (but you can try with device owner rights). To get the IMEI, the app needs to declare the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
```

See for details: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

A workaround would be to **target your app to Android 9 (API level 28) or lower**.

You can get the example of the device owner app [here](https://github.com/h-mdm/hmdm-android) (this is my open source MDM project). In that example, the app retrieves IMEI on Android 10 using this way and declaring **android.permission.READ_PHONE_state** only.

UPDATE - July 2020: On some builds of Android 10 (for example Samsung Galaxy A01), the IMEI is now not returned even if the app targets to API level 28.